# Can you do a FOREACH loop in T-Sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am newbie in SQL Server and I have a big trouble.
I want to execute a update query for each value of idp column @table1 . Values of LaysName column are NULL . 
My simple question is: How can I loop @table1 ?
Here is my Script:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE ( idp )  
INSERT into @table1 SELECT NCid FROM dbo.NorthwindCustomer

    FOREACH idp in @table1
    BEGIN
       UPDATE dbo.LaysCustomer
       SET  LaysName = (SELECT Name FROM dbo.NorthwindCustomer WHERE NCid = idp)
       WHERE LCid = idp
    END
```

Thank you to all !

Comment: You dont need loop, UPDATE can modify many records at once. Wchich column would you like to update?

Comment: @PawełDyl I want to update LaysName column in dbo.LaysCustomer table

Answer (score 5):

No need a loop. You can use [UPDATE FROM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx).

```
UPDATE dbo.LaysCustomer
SET  LaysName = T.Name
FROM dbo.NorthwindCustomer T
WHERE 
    LaysCustomer.LCid = T.NCid
```

Comment: bEFORE EXECUTING YOUR QUERY , i WANT TO SAY THAT Values of LaysName column are NULL .

Comment: @mynhylisti You mean that if `LaysName` is null then update?

Answer (score 0):

Use Set Based approach..

```
UPDATE c
set c.name=n.name
from
dbo.LaysCustomer c
join
dbo.NorthwindCustomer n
on 
N.NCid =c.idp
```

Comment: bEFORE EXECUTING YOUR QUERY , i WANT TO SAY THAT Values of LaysName column are NULL .

Answer (score 0):

Update can work with many records at once. You also don't need local table. Take a look at this query:

```
UPDATE dbo.LaysCustomer SET LaysName=C.Name
FROM dbo.NorthwindCustomer C
WHERE LCid=C.NCid
```

If you really want to use @table1 (it's example?) you can use:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE ( idp int )  
INSERT into @table1 SELECT NCid FROM dbo.NorthwindCustomer

UPDATE dbo.LaysCustomer SET LaysName=C.Name
FROM dbo.NorthwindCustomer C
JOIN @table1 T ON C.NCid=T.idp
WHERE LCid=C.NCid
```

But, as I said, I prefer direct transfer.